# Jquery replace with and restore old value when clicked again same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `css` class to style some `divs`,

When I click one of these `divs`, I am able to replace the `class` with new values. However, I want to restore its `default` value when clicked a div class **class="some_div"** again. So, I'd like to show **class="new_div"** only once.

Thanks in advance

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".some_div").click(function () {  
        var divId = $(this).attr("id");
        var divVideo = $(this).attr("data-video"); 

    $(this).replaceWith('<div class="new_div" id="' + divId + '"  data-video="' + divVideo + '" > New div </div>');
 
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="some_div" id="my-video1" data-video="video1.mp4">
    some div
</div>
<div class="some_div" id="my-video2" data-video="video2.mp4">
    some div
</div>
<div class="some_div" id="my-video3" data-video="video2.mp4">
    some div
</div>
```

Comment: You could save the old value in an array and then retreive the array on click again.

Comment: i can imagine the logic but i tried many things couldnt achive. because i am new on jquery @Nicolas

Comment: i'll add a response with what i'm thinking give me a few minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean toggling its data? Try this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".changeable").click(function() {
        var _old = $(this).attr("data-content") || "old";
        var _new = $(this).html();
        $(this).attr("data-content", _new);
        $(this).html(_old);
    });
})
```

EDIT: Here's your solution: https://jsfiddle.net/549oz76d/1/

Comment: i have tired your code it restore old value when clicked same div  again. but what i need is , when clicked **some_div** show   **new_div**  and when clicked another **some_div** restore **new_div**  with old values.. :)

Comment: sorry my english is not perfect. Your code works fine but problem is when i clicked another  **some_div**  want to restore   **new_div** ...

Comment: @user2983865 The code in your example does not have any `new_div`s. Do you perhaps want it so you only have one at a time?

Comment: here is the new_div : `$(this).replaceWith('<div class="new_div" id="' + divId + '"  data-video="' + divVideo + '" > New div </div>');`

Comment: yes i want it one at a time when clicked some_div .. and when clicked some_div again want to show new_div over there

Comment: @user2983865 Please upvote and accept this answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: its very close what i need it i will try to pass  id and data-video and if its working i will accept .. thank u soo much

Comment: @user2983865 It doesn't touch other attributes such as id and data-*

Comment: do u mean i cant use id and data-* ?

Comment: @user2983865 It does not change those values at all. You don't need to reassign them because they are left untouched.

Comment: @user2983865 You can

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i would do, keep the info in an array at the position of the current id and retreive it on the second click.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var oldData = {};
$(".some_div").click(function () {
    var divId = $(this).attr("id");
    //Validate if the array contains old data.
    if(!oldData.hasOwnProperty(divId){
        //When using data attribute you can access them using .data()
        var divVideo = $(this).data("video"); 
        //Save current value in the array at the position of the current id.
        oldData[divId] = {
            'divVideo': divVideo,
            'html': $(this).html()
        };
        //Replace
        $(this).replaceWith('<div class="new_div" id="' + divId + '"  data-video="' + divVideo + '" > New div </div>');
    } else {
        //Replace the old HTML
        $(this).html(oldData[divId].html);
        //Replace old Video
        $(this).data("video", oldData[divId].divVideo);
    }
});
})
```

Comment: when i try your code not clickable nothing happaned

Comment: I made a fiddle, and changed a few things https://jsfiddle.net/0c1vubb0/

Comment: First of all, you changed the class of your div so it was not accessible anymore in the `$('.some_div')`selector, Also, you had to add back your Jquery listener since it's was dynamicly added, Finally i decided to only replace the HTML because i think this was the only things you changed.

Comment: its working now but it restore when clicked **new_div** ,  what i need is , when clicked another **some_div** want to restore **new_div**,

Comment: well you could use the same method and save every states, and then resote them, i showed you what i had in mind, i'm not gonna code it for you.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it with jQuerys toggle function. I don't know if this is the best solution though.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".toggle1").click(function () {  
 $( ".some_div1" ).toggle();
});

$(".toggle2").click(function () {  
 $( ".some_div2" ).toggle();
});

$(".toggle3").click(function () {  
 $( ".some_div3" ).toggle();
});
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toggle1" id="my-video1" data-video="video1.mp4">
    <div class="some_div1">some div</div>
 <div class="some_div1" style="display: none">New DIV</div>
</div>
<div class="toggle2" id="my-video2" data-video="video2.mp4">
    <div class="some_div2">some div</div>
 <div class="some_div2" style="display: none">New DIV</div>
</div>
<div class="toggle3" id="my-video3" data-video="video2.mp4">
    <div class="some_div3">some div</div>
 <div class="some_div3" style="display: none">New DIV</div>
</div>
```

Hope it helped.

Comment: thank u but i dont want to hide it with css because i want to use video player so it will be really heavy

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(function () {
$(".some_div").click(function () {
      var divId = $(this).attr("id");
      var divVideo = $(this).attr("data-video");
      var n = '<div class="new_div" id="' + divId + '"  data-video="' + divVideo + '" > New div </div>';
      var $old = $(this).attr("data-content") || n;
      var $new = $(this).html();
      $(this).attr("data-content", $new);
      $(this).html($old);
 });
});
```